# how to pass the xml suite name as parameter when running test with Azure DevOps pipeline using yaml file for Maven project

Tags: maven, yaml, azure-pipelines, pom.xml

We have created a selenium project to run functional test.
We have smoke suite, functional suite and regression suite available.
In my pom file, I parameterized the xml suite name and pass the suite name to run in command line as below.

pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

In command line I can give which suite to run as below.

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=regression.xml
```

Now I have created a Azure DevOps pipeline to run my test.
In yaml file, I have added below part to run the pom.xml.

```
    steps:
  - task: Maven@3
    inputs:
     mavenPomFile: './pom.xml'
```

But how can I mention in yaml file, which suite to run with the pipeline?

Comment: Please read the usage tags for the tags you have used.

Comment: I edited the tags @torek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I mention in yaml file, which suite to run with the pipeline?

You can define the parameters value in the **options** field in Maven task.

For example:

```
- task: Maven@3
  displayName: 'Maven pom.xml'
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: './pom.xml'
    goals: 'test'
    options: 'test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=regression.xml'
```

For more info, you can refer to this doc about [maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops).

Comment: @Sanjika, just an FYI, it's polite to flag it as the answer.  It helps others and also rewards those who helped you out.